# How to change woocommerce reviews template from single product reviews tab?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change reviews tab content title(not reviews title but title inside reviews content) from h3 => p

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tab', 98);
function woo_rename_tab($tabs) {
$tabs['description']['title'] = 'More info';return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: i dont want to change tab title. I want to change title in content that tab shows $tab['reviews']['callback'] gives me <h3>title</h3> coments and i want h3 to be p or span

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'bump_review_product_tabs', 98 );   
 function bump_review_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_array ( $tabs['reviews'] ) ) { 
        $tabs['reviews'] = array(
            'title' => 'Reviews',
            'callback'  => function() {
                printf('For dropping a review you will have to <a href="%s">login</a>.', get_site_url(null, '/my-account'));
            }
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
 }
```